# Pagina pierde estilos

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, base-de-datos

Alguien podria ayudarme guiandome sobre como saber cual es el problema por el cual mi pagina pierde los estilo css... es una pagina de noticias que estoy creando, carga datos mediante Ajax al hacer scroll hasta el final, tipo scroll infinito, funcionaba bien, pero hice unos cambios en la base de datos y se quedo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe alguna manera de saber que esta mal, y por que no esta reconociendo los estilos css? Cabe recalcar que la hoja de estilos esta perfectamente ligada a la pagina:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

Este es el codigo de index.php, que recibe datos de la tabla Noticia1, la cual tiene varios campos como Titulo, Subtitulo, Autor etc etc, a su vez este codigo posee un script cargara datos mediante Ajax cada vez que el scroll llegue al final de la pagina. Cada vez que esto suceda enviara por URL la variable "pagina" hacia datos.php, la variable "pagina" se incrementara en 7, para cargar mas datos:

```
//index.php
<?php
//Crear Variables para conexion Noticias Principales
$host = "localhost";
$user = "*********";
$pw = "*********";
$dataBase1 = "kautivai_DatosDeNoticias";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $dataBase1) or die("Problemas al conectar con base de datos 'kautivai_DatosDeNoticias'");

$obtener_filas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1");
$numero_de_fila = mysqli_num_rows($obtener_filas)+1;

    // Ejecutas las consulta 
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 WHERE ID = '$numero_de_fila'") or die("Error al realizar consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    while($final = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="author" content="Kautiva Communication Networks">
<meta name="keywords" content="Noticias, virales, videos">
<meta name="description" content="Noticias virales">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="imagenes/K_alfa.png" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css?v=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $dataBase1) or die ("no se ha podido conectar");
    $cuantos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Numero FROM Noticia1");
    $cuantoes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cuantos);
    $Numero = $cuantoes["Numero"];
    $Numero = $Numero/10;
    echo "var Numero = $Numero;";
?>      

//console.log(Numero);
let acum = -1;
let acumulador = () => {
    acum++
    console.log(acum);
}

var pagina = 0.7;

function cargardatos(){
        // Petición AJAX
        acumulador();
        if (acum >= Numero) {
            console.log("error")
        } else {
            $("#loader").html("<img src='imagenes/loading.gif' style='width:135px; height:100px;'>");
            $.get("datos.php?pagina="+pagina,
                function(data){
                    if (data != "") {
                        $(".mensaje:last").after(data); 
                    }
                    $('#loader').empty();
                }
            );
        }               
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Carga inicial    
    cargardatos();
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        pagina++;
        cargardatos();
    }                   
});

</script>

<div id="contenedorHeader">
<header>
    <div id="centrado">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="imagenes/kautivaLogo.jpg" id="logo2"></a>
        <img src="imagenes/menu.png" id="menuIcon">
        <ul>
            <a><li>INICIO</li></a>
            <a href="deportes.html"><li>DEPORTES</li></a>
            <a href="edicion.html"><li>VIDEOS</li></a>
            <a href="noticia.php"><li>VIRALES</li></a>
            <a href="contacto.html"><li>CONTACTO</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
</div>

       <ul id="menu2">
            <a href="index.html"><li>INICIO</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>DEPORTES</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>VIDEOS</li></a>
            <a href="noticia.html"><li>VIRALES</li></a>
            <a href="contacto.php"><li>CONTACTO</li></a>
        </ul>

        <div id="CajaRedesPC">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/KautivaOficial/"><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/fdefacebook.png" class="redes"></div></a>
            <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/birdTwitter.png" class="redes"></div></a>
            <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/google.png" class="redes"></div></a>
            <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/linkedin.png" class="redes"></div></a>
            <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/pinterest.png" class="redes"></div></a>
        </div>

<div id="general" >
    <h1 class="indicadores">Destacados de hoy</h1>

    <hr class="barrasHorizontales" size="3px" color="#1A354C" width="100%" noshade="noshade" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; opacity: 1;">

    <!--================================================ Bloque Principal ===============================================-->
    <section id="general2">
        <article id="articleIzquierdo">
            <div id="NOTBIG1">
                <div id="fotoB1"><? echo '<img src="'.$final['RutaImagen'].'" class="PORTADAS1">'; ?></div>

                <h3 id="Etiqueta1" style="color: #20a2e3; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><?php echo $final['Etiqueta']; ?></h3>

                <hr size="1px" width="100%" noshade="noshade" style="margin: 10px auto; opacity: 0.3;">

                <h1 class="titulosMain" id="Titulo1"><?php echo $final['Titulo']; ?></h1>
                <h1 class="Subtitulos" id="Subtitulo1"><?php echo $final['Subtitulo']; ?></h1>
                <p style="color: #2E2E2E; font-weight: lighter; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;">Por: <span style="color: #1279a8;"><?php echo $final['Autor']; ?> <span style="color: #2E2E2E;">|</span></span>&nbsp;<span><?php echo $final['Fecha']; ?></span></p>
                <p class="resumenTitulos"><?php echo $final['Texto']; ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
    } //Cierre del primer while
?>


<?php
    // Ejecutas las consulta 
    $obtener_filas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1");
    $numero_de_fila = mysqli_num_rows($obtener_filas);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 WHERE ID = '$numero_de_fila'") or die("Error al realizar consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    while($final2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){ 
?>

                <div id="NOTBIG2">
                <div id="fotoB2"><? echo '<img src="'.$final2['RutaImagen'].'" class="PORTADAS1">'; ?></div>

                <h3 id="Etiqueta2" style="color: #10A2E5; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><?php echo $final2['Etiqueta']; ?></h3>

                <hr size="1px" width="100%" noshade="noshade" style="margin: 10px auto; opacity: 0.3; ">

                <h1 class="titulosMain" id="Titulo2"><?php echo $final2['Titulo']; ?></h1>
                <h1 class="Subtitulos" id="Subtitulo2"><?php echo $final2['Subtitulo']; ?></h1>
                <p style="color: #2E2E2E; font-weight: lighter; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;">Por: <span style="color: #1279a8;"><?php echo $final2['Autor']; ?> <span style="color: #2E2E2E;">|</span></span>&nbsp;<span><?php echo $final2['Fecha']; ?></span></p>
                <p class="resumenTitulos"><?php echo $final2['Texto']; ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
    } //Cierre del segundo while
?>


<?php
    // Ejecutas las consulta 
    $obtener_filas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1");
    $numero_de_fila = mysqli_num_rows($obtener_filas) - 1;
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 WHERE ID = '$numero_de_fila'") or die("Error al realizar consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    while($final3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){ 
?>

                <div id="NOTBIG3">
                <div id="fotoB3"><? echo '<img src="'.$final3['RutaImagen'].'" class="PORTADAS1">'; ?></div>

                <h3 id="Etiqueta3" style="color: #10A2E5; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"><?php echo $final3['Etiqueta']; ?></h3>

                <hr size="1px" width="100%" noshade="noshade" style="margin: 10px auto; opacity: 0.3; ">

                <h1 class="titulosMain" id="Titulo3"><?php echo $final3['Titulo']; ?></h1>
                <h1 class="Subtitulos" id="Subtitulo3"><?php echo $final3['Subtitulo']; ?></h1>
                <p style="color: #2E2E2E; font-weight: lighter; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;">Por: <span style="color: #1279a8;"><?php echo $final3['Autor']; ?> <span style="color: #2E2E2E;">|</span></span>&nbsp;<span><?php echo $final3['Fecha']; ?></span></p>
                <p class="resumenTitulos"><?php echo $final3['Texto']; ?></p>
            </div>

<?php
    } //Cierre del tercer while
?>



            </article>

        <article id="articleDerecho">
<?php
    // Ejecutas las consulta 
    $obtener_filas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1");
    $numero_de_fila = mysqli_num_rows($obtener_filas) - 2;
    $result4 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 WHERE ID = '$numero_de_fila'") or die("Error al realizar consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    while($final4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){ 
?>
                <div id="not2">
                <div id="foto2"><?php echo "<img src='".$final4['RutaImagen']."' class='PORTADAS1'>"; ?></div>
                <h1 class="titulosSecundarios" id="Titulo4"><?php echo $final4['Titulo']; ?></h1>
                <h1 class="SubtitulosPequenos" id="Subtitulo1"><?php echo $final4['Subtitulo']; ?></h1>
                    <p style="color: #2E2E2E; font-weight: lighter; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;">Por: <span style="color: #1279a8;"><?php echo $final4['Autor']; ?></p>
                <p class="resumenTitulos2"><?php echo $final4['Texto']; ?> </p>
            </div>
<?php
    } //Cierre del cuarto while
?>



<?php
    // Ejecutas las consulta 
    $obtener_filas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1");
    $numero_de_fila = mysqli_num_rows($obtener_filas) - 3;
    $result5 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 WHERE ID = '$numero_de_fila'") or die("Error al realizar consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    while($final5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)){ 
?>
            <div id="not3">
                <div id="foto3"><?php echo "<img src='".$final5['RutaImagen']."' class='PORTADAS1'>"; ?></div>
                <h1 class="titulosSecundarios" id="Titulo5"><?php echo $final5['Titulo']; ?></h1>
                <h1 class="SubtitulosPequenos" id="Subtitulo1"><?php echo $final5['Subtitulo']; ?></h1>
                <p style="color: #2E2E2E; font-weight: lighter; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;">Por: <span style="color: #1279a8;"><?php echo $final5['Autor']; ?></p>
                <p class="resumenTitulos2"><?php echo $final5['Texto']; ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
    } //Cierre del quinto while
?>



<?php
    // Ejecutas las consulta 
    $obtener_filas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1");
    $numero_de_fila = mysqli_num_rows($obtener_filas) - 4;
    $result6 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 WHERE ID = '$numero_de_fila'") or die("Error al realizar consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    while($final6 = mysqli_fetch_array($result6)){ 
?>
            <div id="not5">
                <div id="foto5"><?php echo "<img src='".$final6['RutaImagen']."' class='PORTADAS1'>"; ?></div>
                <h1 class="titulosSecundarios" id="Titulo6"><?php echo $final6['Titulo']; ?></h1>
                <h1 class="SubtitulosPequenos" id="Subtitulo1"><?php echo $final6['Subtitulo']; ?></h1>
                <p style="color: #2E2E2E; font-weight: lighter; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;">Por: <span style="color: #1279a8;"><?php echo $final6['Autor']; ?></p>
                <p class="resumenTitulos2"><?php echo $final6['Texto']; ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
    } //Cierre del sexto while
?>



<?php
    // Ejecutas las consulta 
    $obtener_filas = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1");
    $numero_de_fila = mysqli_num_rows($obtener_filas) - 5;
    $result7 = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 WHERE ID = '$numero_de_fila'") or die("Error al realizar consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    while($final7 = mysqli_fetch_array($result7)){ 
?>
            <div id="not6">
                <div id="foto6"><?php echo "<img src='".$final7['RutaImagen']."' class='PORTADAS1'>"; ?></div>
                <h1 class="titulosSecundarios" id="Titulo7"><?php echo $final7['Titulo']; ?></h1>
                <h1 class="SubtitulosPequenos" id="Subtitulo1"><?php echo $final7['Subtitulo']; ?> </h1>
                <p style="color: #2E2E2E; font-weight: lighter; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;">Por: <span style="color: #1279a8;"><?php echo $final7['Autor']; ?></p>
                <p class="resumenTitulos2"><?php echo $final7['Texto']; ?></p>
            </div>
<?php
    }//Cierre del septimo while
?>


</article>

        <div id="banner1"><img src="imagenes/bannerGO.jpg" id="bannerPrincipalImagen"></div>
        <div id="bannerResponsive"><img src="imagenes/banner5.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
    </section>


    <!--================================================ Bloque Principal ===============================================-->

    <!--  Tercer Bloque Tercer Bloque Tercer Bloque Tercer Bloque Tercer Bloque Tercer Bloque Tercer Bloque -->
    <h1 class="indicadores" style=" width: 100%; height: 20px; color: #10A2E5; display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size: 17px;">Más noticias</h1>

    <hr class="barrasHorizontales" size="3px" color="#1A354C" width="100%" noshade="noshade" style="margin-top: 0; opacity: 1;">

    <div id="main3">
        <div id="ForLoadMore1">
            <div class="mensaje"></div>  //Div en donde se cargaran los datos
        </div>
        <div id="loader"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="cajaRedesSociales">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/KautivaOficial/"><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/fdefacebook.png" class="redes"></div></a>
        <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/birdTwitter.png" class="redes"></div></a>
        <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/google.png" class="redes"></div></a>
        <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/linkedin.png" class="redes"></div></a>
        <a><div class="redesBox"><img src="imagenes/pinterest.png" class="redes"></div></a>
    </div>

</div>

<footer>
    <p style="color: #fff; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: lighter; ">&copy; 2017 Kautiva Social Communication - All rights reserved</p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Nosotros</li>
            <li>Términos de uso</li>
            <li>Sponsor</li>
            <a href="contacto.html"><li>Contacto</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

En la pagina datos.php, se recibe la variable "pagina" y se la usa para enviar los datos de las respectivas filas solicitadas cada vez que se incrementa la variable "pagina":

```
<?php   
//Crear Variables para conexion Noticias Principales
$host = "localhost";
$user = "*******";
$pw = "*******";
$dataBase1 = "kautivai_DatosDeNoticias";

$pagina = $_GET['pagina']; //se recibe la variable pagina
$num = 10; 
$principio = $pagina * $num; //Se establece el inicio de la fila a mostrar (0.7 * 10 = 7), el intervalo a mostrar sera desde la fila 8 (contando desde la ultima) en forma descendente.
$fin = 5;

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $dataBase1) or die ("no se ha podido conectar");  
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM Noticia1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT {$principio},{$fin}") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));    

        while($final = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<div class='mensaje'>
                <div class=\"not7\"><div class=\"fotosMain3\" id=\"foto18\"><img src='".$final['RutaImagen']."' class='PORTADAS1'></div><div class=\"TextoDerecha\"><h3 id=\"Etiqueta16\" style=\"color: #10A2E5; font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;\">".$final['Etiqueta']."</h3><hr class=\"barrasNuevas\" size=\"1px\" width=\"100%\" noshade=\"noshade\" style=\"margin: 10px auto; opacity: 0.3;\"><a href='noticia.php?title=".$final['Titulo']."' style='text-decoration: none;'><h1 class=\"titulosMain3\" id=\"Titulo19\">".$final['Titulo']."</h1></a><h1 class=\"Subtitulos\" id=\"Subtitulo15\">".$final['Subtitulo']."</h1><p style=\"color: #2E2E2E; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;\">Por: <span style=\"color: #1279a8;\">".$final['Autor']."<span style=\"color: #2E2E2E;\">|</span></span>&nbsp;<span>".$final['Fecha']."</span></p><p class=\"main3Textos\" id=\"main3Textos-12\">".substr($final['Texto'], 0, 200)."...</p></div></div>
                    </div>";
        }

?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor cómo debería estar si funcionara correctamente y cuál es la diferencia con lo que ves actualmente? ¿Podrías explicar también qué modificaciones hiciste en la base de datos para orientarnos todo lo posible? Gracias.

Comment: Hola.. No podria pegarte un imagen de como se veia antes, porque no puedo, pero si te podria decir es estaba muy bien estructurado en divs, se veia ordenado y las letras no se veian con caracteres especiales.

Comment: Eso significa que te falta cargar jQuery antes que ese bloque de javascript.

Comment: ¿Qué modificaciones hiciste en la base de datos? Todo parece apuntar a un problema en el documento HTML. Si compartes el contenido o la parte más relevante podremos ayudarte a corregir el error de manera eficiente. Ese error en particular es por intentar hacer uso de jQuery antes de cargarlo, pero quizá has perdido los javascripts por algún motivo tangencial (registros en la base de datos que contenían las URLs a importar, alguna etiqueta HTML sin cerrar que impide que la de jQuery se interprete correctamente, etc). Sin demasiadas posibilidades sin ver al menos el código HTML generado.

Comment: ¿Podrías revisar la consola (déjala limpia antes de recargar la página) y la pestaña network en busca de archivos no encontrados (error 404) u otros errores en la consola?

Comment: Oscar, Gracias por tus respuestas, he colocado en una mejor posicion el script, y los errores han desaparecido.. pero aun la estructura se mantiene sin estilos. He borrado y he vuelto a crear la tabla de mi base de datos y no se arregla.. no se si seria conveniente ponerte todo el codigo aqui, o mejor te doy el link la pagina en el servidor para que se te haga mas sencillo revisar el codigo fuente en tu nvegador. Los cambios que hice fueron simples.. para ver como funcionaba mi pagina, copie las filas de la tabla para aumentarlas, pero una vez que vi que funcionaba bien, las borre, y paso esto

Comment: ¿Usas algún framework como Laravel, Slim, etc? Un enlace a la web ayudaría muchísimo aunque no pudiera ver el código PHP o contenido de la base de datos (que probablemente sea necesario si solo con el enlace no se puede ver claramente qué provoca los problemas). Si no me da tiempo a verlo hoy (son las 0:20h) lo revisaré mañana o quizá otro compañero lo use para averiguar tu problema y solucionarlo.

Comment: Lo unico que uso es Jquery, el link de la pagina es www.kautiva.info, es una pagina de noticias que quiero hacer, que funcionaba, pero ahora se quedo asi y no tengo idea de que o por que se da ese problema. He estado buscando errores de sintaxis en la pagina principal index.php, pero no encuentro ninguno. Te explico la pagina para la entiendas, la pagina index.php, trae info de la base de datos, que tiene una tabla autoincrementable por ID, empezando desde el 1, trae los datos en forma descendente, mostrando la ultima fila siempre en al inicio de la pagina. he puesto el codigo en la pregunta.

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza en responder. ¿Algún avance? ¿Lo solucionaste? Acabo de leer tu respuesta, he visitado la página y se ve bien, no sé si porque encontraste el error o por otro motivo.

Comment: Si, el problema era que tenia el <head> dentro del while() de PHP, eso causaba confusion al navegador..!

Comment: Entonces el problema no fue hacer los cambios en la base de datos, si no en el código PHP, ¿no? Entonces no deberías responderte y darte la respuesta como correcta, si no borrar la pregunta o bien exponer correctamente el problema para que pueda ser útil en un futuro.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Resuelto, las etiquetas `<head></head>` estaban dentro del bucle while() de PHP, lo que hice fue sacar dichas etiquetas del bucle y el problema se soluciono.

Comment: Hola Marvin, esta respuesta ha sido marcada com de muy baja calidad por la comunidad, y es un poco confusa (PHP se ejecuta en el lado del servidor, no en el cliente/navegador). Por favor, edítala para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿el orden de qué instrucciones? ¿Puedes poner la parte que cambiaste antes y después de hacer el cambio?

Answer (score 0):

prueba agregando ?v=1 en el href del estilo, a veces sucede que la caché se queda almacenada y no se actualizan los cambios recientes del estilo.

Tu etiqueta quedaría así

> link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css?v=1"

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. En las respuestas deberías exponer la solución y no hacer preguntas o sugerir comprobaciones. Usa los comentarios para que realice pruebas y cuando estés seguro de problema redacta la respuesta con la solución. Pásate por [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Las causas que ocasionan dicho error son:

1.-Comprueba que has cargado la librería de jquery .

```
<head>
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 </head>
```

2.-No haya javascript ejecutándose antes de que la librería de jquery se haya cargado  o algún plugin que utilice jquery ejecutándose también antes.

Una página puede ser manipulada sin riesgo de errores solamente cuando el documento está listo. jQuery se encarga de detectar dicho estado en nuestro lugar. El código incluido dentro de $( document ).ready() se ejecutará solamente cuando el modelo de objeto de documento (DOM) esté listo para ejecutar código Javascript. Sabiendo esto, cuando esté listo se llama a la función cargarDatos() que debes tener definida .

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. En las respuestas deberías exponer la solución y no hacer nuevas preguntas, sugerir comprobaciones o dar soluciones probables. Usa los comentarios para que realicen pruebas y cuando estés seguro del problema redacta la respuesta con la solución. Pásate por [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK, gracias, soy nuevo e intento ayudar. Estoy convencido que debe ser por lo que he puesto, pero si que es cierto que no debería exponer mis posibles dudas a que pudiera ser otra cosa. Gracias por el aporte, ahora iré al link.

Comment: Hay que encontrar el problema raíz, no sólo parchear el síntoma. Es probable que al tocar la base de datos alterara la estructura del documento de manera que impida la interpretación de la carga de jQuery, como por ejemplo anidar dos etiquetas `<script>` por error o no cerrar una o incluirla dentro de otra etiqueta (como un comentario `<!-- ... ->`, etc) o alterar algún registro como la URL de carga, etc. Hay que encontrar qué modificó o alteró su HTML al tocar la base de datos para que de funcionar correctamente ahora no funcione jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Todos los src scripts y estilos css no tienen porque estar en el head
Prueba a agregar jquerry y anteponerlo a las demás funciones que tienes, prueba también a añadir códigos en este trozo de JavaScript onload.

```
window.onload = function() { 
  //parte de tu código aquí que quieres que se ejecute en la carga de la página
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. En las respuestas deberías exponer la solución y no hacer nuevas preguntas, sugerir comprobaciones o dar soluciones probables. Usa los comentarios para que realicen pruebas y cuando estés seguro del problema redacta la respuesta con la solución. Pásate por [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).